# How to query for field values that all documents have in common?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got the following simple ElasticSearch query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "categories": "1234"
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns a number of documents containing a structure like this:

```
{
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "value": 20
        },
        {
            "name": "bar",
            "value": 30
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I have to alter the above query so ElasticSearch returns a set of values in `properties.name` that *all* result documents have in common?

Comment: You have a query for `categories` and the results refer to `name`, `value` and `properties`. You might want to clarify what exactly you have tried and what is the desired outcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with a simple query. One of the solution is to use [a term aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation), like this one:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "categories": "1234"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "properties_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "properties.name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will get a similar response:

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 10,
    "hits": [{...}]
  }
  "aggregations": {
    "properties_name": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [{
        "key": "foo",
        "doc_count": 10
      }, {
        "key": "bar",
        "doc_count": 4
      }, {}]
    }
  }
}
```

You usual results will be available under `hits`, and the aggregation results under `aggregations`.

Then you can use hits.total (10) to find properties_names which are present in all documents. You simply need to iterate over buckets, and keep ones with doc_count == hits.total

In this example only "foo" properties is present in all documents